# How to do this using Thymleaf?

Tags: java, html, jsp, thymeleaf

This is my code that is using JSP:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

This is what I try:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  th:attr="value = ${_csrf.token}"/>
```

I dont  know how to atributte a value to the name of the html.

Answer (score 1):

This should look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

[List of thymeleaf attributes.](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes)