# How to do this using thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, thymeleaf

I am working with Spring Security and Thymeleaf.

The code below is using JSP:

```jsp
<c:url var="save" value="/usuario/save?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}"/>
    <form:form modelAttribute="usuario" action="${save}" method="post" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This is my code using Thymeleaf, it don't work:

```jsp
<form action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/usuario/save?_csrf=(${_csrf.token})}" th:object="${usuario}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I get this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/springsecurity/usuario/save?_csrf=&c5cea050-9e39-4220-b7fb-576964def023
```

But my values are `_csrf=c5cea050-9e39-4220-b7fb-576964def023` without `&` before the code `c5cea050-9e39-4220-b7fb-576964def023`

[image]

Comment: Does it work with <th:form> instead of form?

Comment: @Raphael I don't understood , what means <th:form> , when I tryed ,it  don't submit the form!

Comment: <th:form method="post" th:action="@{/usuario/save?_csrf=(${_csrf.token})}" th:object="${usuario}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Dont't use th:action and action at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you use Thymeleaf together with Spring Security, a hidden CSRF input is automatically added. If it is not, try adding this in your form:

```xml
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}">
```

Comment: Thank you ,  but I already try to use this code , and it  not work, then I solved my problem with  th:action="@{/usuario/save?(_csrf=${_csrf.token})}"

Comment: @PenaPintada Why close?

Comment: No problem, forget what I asked for. But l,ook this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635327/how-to-do-this-using-thymleaf